# Flurry's AppCircle in Android App returing non-compatible apps

Tags: android, flurry

I'm using Flurry's AppCircle Api to show apps in a custom UI format.

Some of the Apps I get in the "Offers" are NOT COMPATIBLE with the
phone I'm using.
This results in a "not found" error when I click it to open the
Market.

Does the API filter not-compatible Apps?

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Flurry officially told me that they can't filter incompatible apps at this point.